# Firebird: DBExpress or native components?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firebird, dbexpress

I am starting with Firebird and have found components to access a database by Devart.
They offer native components ([IBDAC](http://www.devart.com/ibdac/)) or [DBExpress](http://www.devart.com/dbx/interbase/) drivers. (I am using Delphi XE2 Pro which doesn't include Firebird drivers)

I guess native components are a bit faster, but that's not too important for me.

What are the advantages/disadvantages of each approach and why should I choose one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**IBdac**

- your application is tied to firebird
- you are familiar with bde or ado
- performance
- maximal Firebird support

**DBexpress**

- portability (it is easy to port you application to anther database).
- upgrade pro edition to enterprise so you can use one supplied by
  embarcadero.

---

You can check [Devart FAQ](http://www.devart.com/ibdac/faq.html#q61).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems that I get the best of both sides using the UniDAC components instead of IBDAC. Native components but able to use several types of DBs.

Answer (score 5):

Check [Anydac](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/). It is universal data access library, but supports most of [Firebird specific features](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/personalized-api.html#firebird) including - multiple transactions, database events, services (backup/restore), etc. The performance is very good. Sorry, i cannot imagine dbExpress advantages over Anydac.

Comment: Using AnyDAC is later simply migrate to other DBMS

Answer (score 3):

[FIBPlus](http://www.devrace.com) and [UIB](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=5) are also good choice

Comment: I looked at both, but they do not support XE2 yet. FIBPlus's latest version is for Delphi 2010 and UIB's latest version is for Delphi XE.

Comment: UIB is free. +1 for a free option.

Answer (score 1):

Native components can support database specific functions. I've missed event support with DBExpress when using 3rd party driver from Upscene.

DBExpress should make it easier to create database agnostic application, but I've no experience about that.

Answer (score 1):

**[ZEOSlib](http://zeos.firmos.at/index.php?sid=fe07d78a8b1dbf02fcc18c86424ff782)** might be a nice alternative, actively developed and supporting many databases including Firebird.

Comment: I downloaded the latest revision from their repository yesterday, but there are files (still) missing in order to install it for Delphi XE2.